# Typo in API docs: "temporarility_unavailable"

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

"temporarility" should probably be "temporarily"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in... some deploy, not entirely sure which.

But it is fixed.